# Microsoft Bot Emulator throws "An error occurred while sending the request" when sending a message that expects a Herocard as a response

Tags: bots, botframework

I am developing a chat bot using `QnAMakerServices` and an emulator to train the bot. 
In my QnaDialog.cs, I override one method from the `QnAMakerDialog` which is the `RespondFromQnAMakerResultAsync`.

This is for me to customize the method and create a Herocard as a response. My code goes like this:

```
namespace IMPBot.Dialogs
{
    [Serializable]
    public class QnaDialog : QnAMakerDialog
    {
        public QnaDialog() : base(new QnAMakerService(new QnAMakerAttribute(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnaSubscriptionKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["QnaKnowledgebaseId"], "Sorry, I couldn't find an answer for that. Please rephrase your question and make sure to ask questions only related to Insights Marketplace.", 0.5)))
        {

        }

        protected override async Task RespondFromQnAMakerResultAsync(IDialogContext context, IMessageActivity message, QnAMakerResults result)
        {
            // answer is a string
            var answer = result.Answers.First().Answer;
            if (answer.Contains(';'))
            {
                Activity reply = ((Activity)context.Activity).CreateReply();
                string[] qnaAnswerData = answer.Split(';');
                string title = qnaAnswerData[0];
                string description = qnaAnswerData[1];
                string url = qnaAnswerData[2];
                string imageURL = qnaAnswerData[3];
                HeroCard card = new HeroCard
                {
                    Title = title,
                    Subtitle = description,
                };
                card.Buttons = new List<CardAction>
                {
                    new CardAction(ActionTypes.OpenUrl, "See more", value: url)
                };

                card.Images = new List<CardImage>
                {
                    new CardImage( url = imageURL)
                };
                reply.Attachments.Add(card.ToAttachment());
                //await context.PostAsync(reply);
            }
            else
            {
                await context.PostAsync(answer);
                context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I run the Bot Emulator it throws the following error:

> Exception: An error occurred while sending the request. [File of type 'text/plain']

And it did not show any card.
On the other hand, the log says,

> Warning: The latest bot SDK version is 3.13.0 but the bot is running
>   SDK version 3.12.2. Consider upgrading the bot to the latest SDK.

Is there any connection with the error to what the log says? 
Or did I miss something in the code?

Comment: 2 things: can you add a sample of the content of an answer string? and for the warning, no there is no link but you should update your NuGet package on your project

Comment: @NicolasR what sample content do you mean?

Comment: A sample value of the content you have in your `var answer` during execution, to be able to reproduce on our side